# how to plot multiple plots in one figure in python. I am trying to plot autocorrelation and partial correlation of multiple users for service quality

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

More description of my problem. 
 https://github.com/wsdream/wsdream-dataset/tree/master/dataset2. This dataset contains four features(User ID, Service ID, Time, Service Quality). Service Quality is measured using Throughput or Response Time. This is a Time series forecasting problem.

Where do I need help? 
To apply time series models, first, the stationarity of data has to be checked. So, I went forward to calculate the autocorrelation & partial-autocorrelation. Now, we need to select a web service and two users who invoke this web service. For each such user, we extract service quality data as a series and calculate the autocorrelation & partial-autocorrelation, this will create a total of 8 plots. For this, I am using statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf() and statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_pcaf() respectively. I need to put all the plots in one figure like this[image]

Comment: Please use subplots

Comment: Please put a comment if I need to explain more :)

Comment: @JodyKlymak please explain your approach. I have tried using subplots, but I always end up with errors.

Comment: You could do something like `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(15, 8))` and then `plot_acf(..., ax=axs[0,0])` etc. Each subplot gets accessed via the 2D array of `ax`s. Tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Comment: You may also wish to look at https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf.html  Google `plot_acf subplots` returns many many examples, including on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797648/displaying-statsmodels-plot-acf-and-plot-pacf-side-by-side-in-a-jupyter-notebook